# HTML Update News Page

Tags: html

I have a site which is basically a few HTML Pages. I no have a requirement to create a facility where a site admin can create and maintain a News section.

I am just pondering what my options are?  It needs to be a fairly simple process to maintain news items and ideally not be database driven. Although I'm struggling to see how I can achieve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CuteNews](http://cutephp.com/cutenews/) should do what you want.  It uses a flat file to store the news items so you don't need a database.

Comment: cute is a great solution for what he's asking.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with CuteNews.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood well, but if you mean you have news in static HTML pages and you want to update them, without doing it by hand, you would have to write a script that creates new ones or updates the existing ones, but that's all too complicated in my oppinion.

The way to go is Server-side language (PHP, ASP etc) and database (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc).